# Proving a sequence is increasing and converging as $n\to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Suppose that $x_0 \in (-1,0)$ and $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}+1}-1$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Prove that $x_n \uparrow 0$ as $n\to \infty$. What happens when $x_0 \in [-1,0]$?

Before this, the problems I did had $x_n$ already bounded so I could apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT). Or, it was $x\ge 2$ and I first showed it was bounded and convergent through induction, then used the MCT.

I'm having trouble interpreting the $x_0 \in (-1,0)$. I think I could figure out the rest if someone could help me out getting it started. Wish I had some work to show but I'm not sure how to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, suppose $x_0\in(-1,0)$. More generally, if $x_{n-1}\in(-1,0)$ then $x_{n-1}+1\in(0,1)$ so that
$$
x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}+1}-1\in(-1,0).
$$
Therefore, by an induction argument, $x_n\in(-1,0)$ for all $n$. A consequence of this is that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded from above by $0$. Another consequence is:
$$
x_n+1=\sqrt{x_{n-1}+1}>x_{n-1}+1\implies x_n>x_{n-1}.
$$
Thus, $\{x_n\}$ is also increasing and so converges to some limit $L\in[-1,0]$ satisfying $L=\sqrt{L+1}-1$. There are 2 solutions to this: $L=0$ and $L=-1$. The latter is ruled out because $x_0$ is strictly greater $-1$.

Finally, if $x_0$ is either $0$ or $-1$, then $\{x_n\}$ is a constant sequence in which every $x_n$ equals $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. For the last part, could you elaborate on when it becomes a constant sequence in which every $x_n$ equals $x_0$?

Comment: If $x_{n-1}=0$, what is $x_{n}$? Similarly, $x_{n-1}=-1$ implies $x_n=-1$.

Comment: I believe I got it, thanks.